# localhost apache small problem

Tags: php, apache

i have small problem with apache

apache is automatic securing my varibales!

example

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

link : `http://localhost/file.php?id=sadsad'sadad'asd`

it's output `sadsad\'sadad\'asd`

How i can disable this thing ?

Comment: i have edited files and still getting \' may be i should restart apache! if so , how i can restart!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably seeing the effects of [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).  This is a PHP feature, not an Apache feature.  And you should disable it immediately, because it's stupid.

To disable, follow the link above, and you'll end up on the [Disabling Magic Quotes page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).  As it says there, you'll need to edit your php.ini file, thus:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: @Osama: Did you read the link I provided?  Oh well, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stripslashes` to get rid of the problem:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $id=stripslashes($id);
}
echo $id;
```

Comment: Or better yet, turn off MagicQuotes since it's deprecated and won't be supported in the future.

Comment: No , i want only disable the magic quates from settings without using php functions!

Comment: i have edited files and still getting \' may be i should restart apache! if so , how i can restart! <- sorry this replay for the answer of Oli Charlesworth